# Login implementation using TestNG framework in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am relatively new to selenium webdriver and learning to work on small code using TestNG framework. My test cases are

1. Login Gmail
2. Compose mail
3. Send and verify
4. Logout

When I am not using TestNG, my code is running fine, but when I use TestNG framework

1. It fails after passing first test case.
2. Fails with an error "Unable to locate element"

Here is the image of error message,

[image]

This is my code

```
package autoamtionFramework;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestNG {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
      public void Startup(){
        //Initiate driver
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      }

    @Test(priority=1)
        public void GoogleLogin() throws Exception{

        //Go to Gmail  
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        assertEquals("Sign in", driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).getAttribute("value"));

        //Maximize the window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Clear autofilled and enter username, click next
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("********@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Clear pass and enter password, click submit
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("***********");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PersistentCookie")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //verify login is done
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
        public void CreateMail() throws Exception{  

        //Click on Compose button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        //ENter the reciepient mail id
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']")).sendKeys("********@gmail.com");

        //Enter Subject
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("Selenium Test Mail");

        //ENter mail body
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Ar Au']//div")).sendKeys("Hi SD");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }   

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void SendVerify() throws Exception
        {//Send the email
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Send')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);


        //Go to Sent Items
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Sent Mail']")).click();

        //Verify that mail is sent
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='span']//span[text()='Selenium Test Mail']")) != null)

        {
            System.out.println("Email is sent successfully");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error::Email is not sent!!");
        }
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        //Logout and close the window
    @Test(priority=4)
    public void GmailLogout() throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='gb_b gb_db gb_R']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Sign out')]")).click();

        //Verify Login is done

        String Title = driver.getTitle();

        if ( Title != "+********@gmail.com+")
        {
            System.out.println("Your Gmail is logged out!!");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong. Pls logout manually!!");
        }
      }

      @AfterMethod
      public void Exit(){
        driver.close();
      }
}
```

Comment: Reading only through your import statements I can tell that you are mixing up testNG and JUnit.

Comment: you should try [QMetry Automation framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which is [TestNG selenium extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#use-selenium) where you don't need to manage driver

Answer (score 2):

You initialize driver in `@BeforeMethod`, then open page in first test and then close driver in `@AfterMethod`, and go to the second test. Change `@AfterMethod` to `@AfterClass`.